# Write user defined function in trino

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-superset, trino

When i write udf function in trino, when use after `where` clause. it's ok when i pass param is default value. But when i want display value after select with param is value of column, it cause error:
`2023-11-23T16:37:59.107+0700  ERROR   stage-scheduler io.trino.execution.StageStateMachine    Stage 20231123_093758_00009_t6k2p.0 failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown function implementation: get_rowkey(bigint,varchar,bigint,bigint,bigint):varchar at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:219) at io.trino.metadata.FunctionRegistry$FunctionMap.get(FunctionRegistry.java:957) at io.trino.metadata.FunctionRegistry.get(FunctionRegistry.java:827) at io.trino.metadata.MetadataManager.getFunctionMetadata(MetadataManager.java:2639) at io.trino.metadata.MetadataManager.getFunctionMetadata(MetadataManager.java:2634) at io.trino.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitFunctionCall(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:1226) at io.trino.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitFunctionCall(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:495) at io.trino.sql.tree.FunctionCall.accept(FunctionCall.java:121) at io.trino.sql.tree.StackableAstVisitor.process(StackableAstVisitor.java:27) at io.trino.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.process(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:518) at io.trino.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer.analyze(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:403) at io.trino.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer.analyzeExpressions(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:2711) at io.trino.sql.planner.TypeAnalyzer.getTypes(TypeAnalyzer.java:54) at io.trino.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitScanFilterAndProject(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:1880) at io.trino.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitProject(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:1808) at io.trino.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitProject(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:838) at io.trino.sql.planner.plan.ProjectNode.accept(ProjectNode.java:82) at io.trino.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitOutput(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:926) at io.trino.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitOutput(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:838) at io.trino.sql.planner.plan.OutputNode.accept(OutputNode.java:83) at io.trino.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner.plan(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:534) at io.trino.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner.plan(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:455) at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecutionFactory.create(SqlTaskExecutionFactory.java:79) at io.trino.execution.SqlTask.updateTask(SqlTask.java:448)`

How i can fix this?